# Query on dictionary in python

Tags: python

[{"sku":43900,"name":"Batteries (4-Pack)","type":"HardGood","category": [{"id":"pc5","name":"Housewares"}]]

this is in json file.
i want to load this and make a dictionary in Python from this input.i tired to load but confused how to create dictionary from this input.

```
import json
data = []
json_file=open ('prod.json')
json_str=json_file.read()
json_data=json.loads(json_str)
for items in json_data:
   print(items['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
s = '[{"sku":43900,"name":"Batteries (4-Pack)","type":"HardGood","category": [{"id":"pc5","name":"Housewares"}]}]'
list_of_dicts = json.loads(s)
```

Your json was invalid; I added a `}` in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i am looking for more. I have hundreds of row like this. How to parse the data without typing every time all the Values in dictionary format.